# Proving Open/Closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let A = {$x \in \mathbb{R} | 2 \leq f^2(x) \leq 4 $}. Let B = {$(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2| 1 \leq |x| + |y| < 2$}. Prove if they're open,closed, or whatever they are.

Firstly, I would like to do an intuition check. {$a\leq b\leq c$}, will always be closed? And the same for {$a<b<c$}, will it automatically be open? And if {$a < b \leq c$}, is it not open nor closed?

For the set A, is it acceptable if I use 4 different sequences, to show that the complement is open? Also, is not knowing the points specifically acceptable for it to be a sequence? For example, $x_n := \{x|{f(x) \xrightarrow -2}$}. I wanted to use these 'gimmicky' sequences to show that A is open.

For B, is fixing one variable a legitimate sequence? For example, $(x=0,y_n) := (0,\{2- \frac{1}{n} \})$

Comment: in the usual topology for $\mathbb R$, $[a,c]$ is closed, $(a,c)$ is open, and $(a,c]$ is neither

Comment: For $A$ we would need to know if $f$ is a continuous function. For example, if $f$ is twice the indicator function at 2, $A$ is a closed set

Comment: @perpetuallyconfused am I allowed to immediately say that $2 \leq f^2(x) \leq4$ is closed,  and because $f \in C[a,b]$, A is closed?

Comment: If $f$ is a continuous function on a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then $A$ is the preimage of the closed set $[2,4]$ under the continuous map $f^2$

Comment: WHAT IS $f$?............

Comment: @DanielWainfleet $f$ refers to any function

Comment: If $f(x)=3$ for all $x$, then $A$ is both closed and open since $A = \emptyset$, if $f(x) = 2$ then again $A$ is both closed and open since $A=\mathbb{R}$... There are other functions $f$ for which $A$ is open but not closed, closed but not open or neither closed nor open, can you come up with a function for each of these cases? @AyamGorengPedes

Comment: For $B$ you could prove that $f:\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\to\mathbb R/f(x,y)=|x|+|y|$ is continuous so $f^{-1}([1,2])$ would be closed.

Answer (score 1):

An example for the 1st Q. Let $A$ be $any$ subset of $\Bbb R$ such that $2\in A.$ Let $f(x)=2$ if $x\in A.$ Let $f(x)=0$ if $x\in \Bbb R \setminus A.$